# Retrive objects matching one of the column of associated resource in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mysql2

I have BackgroundJob as

```
class BackgroundJob < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true

end
```

Here resource is Message table

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :background_job, as: :resource

end
```

columns Message: email, text.
Message has email as column

I want to retrieve all the BackgroundJob objects whose resource email column equals to 'demo@example.com' email.

How we can achieve above background_jobs table ?

Message is as resource for BackgroundJob object.

I am using mysql2 database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform `JOIN`, like this:

```
BackgroundJob.joins('INNER JOIN messages ON messages.id = background_jobs.resource_id AND background_jobs.resource_type = "Message"').where(messages: { email: 'demo@example.com' })
```

You can't use `ActiveRecord` built-in mechanism and write simply `joins(:resource)` because it's a polymorphic association and there's no even table like `resources`. That's why you have to write `JOIN` clause on your own.

Comment: Thanks, understood concept. Used by creating scope